# how to know on which control in panel double click is made in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, panel, picturebox, double-click

In vb.net i have one panel in which multiple picture box controls are added. When a double click is made on  picture box, I want to save image of it. 
so how to know on which picture box control in panel double click is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   Private Sub Button2_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  
                                  Handles Pic1.DoubleClick,Pic2.DoubleClick, anyothercontrol.DoubleClick

       //(cast sender to picture control)
       If TypeOf sender Is PictureControl Then
         ControlName = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).Name //use select case for further programming with control
       Else
         ControlName = DirectCast(sender, someothercontrol).Name
       End If
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the DoubleClick event of each picture box. The DoubleClick eventhandler has a Sender parameter which holds the reference to the actual control that raised the event.

Comment: So if there are 20 picture boxes i will have to write two subroutines? So is there any other way by which this can be done by writing single subroutine?

Comment: @vaichidrewar, you need to use handle multiple controls with comma separated control names, also you can check my answer on similar line of @Rhapsody